# How to write a test case for Jersey Rest resouce + Grizzly+mockito

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I am trying to write integration test case for Jersey Using Grizzly and Mockito, Spring, I am not able to mock the service Class. how can I mock the service class which is injected in my Resource class with @AutoWired

```
@AutoWired
MyFirstService myFirstServiceImpl;

@AutoWired
MySecondService mySecondServiceImpl;

    @GET
        @Path("/abc")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response getDetails(@QueryParam("xyz") String xyz,
            @QueryParam("pqr") String pqr) {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
            Map<String, Object> someMap= new HashMap<String, Object>();
            try {

                map.put("a", myFirstServiceImpl.getSomeDetails(xyz);

                map.put("b", mySecondService.getSomeMoreDetails(pqr);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return Response.status(200).entity(gson.toJson(someMap)).build();

        }


Test Class:


@Mock
    private static MySecondService mySecondServiceImpl;;
    @Mock
    private static MyFirstService myFirstServiceImpl;

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        resource = new MyResource();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        resource.setMyFirstService (firstService);
        resource.setSecondService(secondService);

    }

 @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    private DeploymentContext getRestResourcesWithFilter() {
        System.setProperty("jersey.config.test.container.port", "8104");

        ServletDeploymentContext context =
            ServletDeploymentContext
                .forServlet(
                    new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class).property(
                        ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, "true")))
                .addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class).addListener(RequestContextListener.class)
                .initParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
                .build();
        return context;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        SomeOBject object= new SomeObject();

        Object2 obj= new Object2();



        when(myFirstServiceImpl.getSomeDetails(any(String.class))).thenReturn(object);
       when(mySecondService.getSomeMoreDetails(pqr)).thenReturn(obj);

         Response response = target("v1/abc").request().get();

    }
```

This Test case is passing but the service class which I mocked are not mocking I am getting null pointer exception when ever code hits that line

Comment: Look at this `new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class)`. When you pass the class, you are letting the Jersey runtime create the instance. So it will not be the instance with your mocked objects. You can use `new ResourceConfig().register(resource)` to register your instance of the resource class

Comment: Oh and another thing I think _might_ be a problem. `JerseyTest` has a `@Before` method that it implements. It will be called before yours. And in that method, it will create the container. So your `@Before` might be too late. Haven't tested, but I think that's how it works. If that's the case, just create the mocks in the method you create the deployment context. A new container is created for each test method anyway

Comment: And also what is this method `getRestResourcesWithFilter` actually doing? Is it being called somewhere else you are not showing us?

Comment: yup you are right I am calling that method some other place.

Comment: I tried both ways you mentioned, but no luck :(

Comment: So you created the resource class as the first step in `getRestResourcesWithFilter` method (not in the `@Before`), handled the mocks, then used `new ResourceConfig().register(resource)`?

Comment: I just edited my Test case above after modifications

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88154/discussion-between-user2108383-and-peeskillet).

Answer (score 2):

So there are a couple problems

1. The `@Before` method. `JerseyTest` already [implements a `@Before` method](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/test-framework/core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/test/JerseyTest.java#L603), where it creates the test container. So your mocks won't be created in time and the services will be null. Best thing to do is to just create the services in the `configureDeployment()` method, where you are initializing the Jersey application. A new container will be created for each test case, so you will have new mocks for each test.
2. You are simple passing the class to the `ResourceConfig` constructor, which will cause the Jersey runtime to create the instance of the resource class. So after you create the resource class, instead of `new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class)`, do `new ResourceConfig().register(resource)`.

So the `configureDeployment()` method should look more like

```
@Override
public DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
    resource = new MyResource();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    resource.setMyFirstService(firstService);
    resource.setSecondService(secondService);

    ServletDeploymentContext context
            = ServletDeploymentContext.forServlet(
                    new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig().register(resource).property(
                                    ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, "true")))
            .build();
    return context;
}
```

Another problem is that you are not actually passing any query parameters in the request. So in your resource method, the parameters will be null. Your request should look more like

```
target(...).queryParam(key1, value1).queryParam(key2, value2)
```

Here is a complete test

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.ServletDeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

public class MockitoTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static interface Service {

        String getMessage(String name);
    }

    @Mock
    private Service service;

    @Path("mock")
    public static class MyResource {

        private Service service;

        public void setService(Service service) {
            this.service = service;
        }

        @GET
        public String get(@QueryParam("name") String name) {


            return service.getMessage(name);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {

        MyResource resource = new MyResource();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        resource.setService(service);

        ServletDeploymentContext context
                = ServletDeploymentContext.forServlet(
                        new ServletContainer(new ResourceConfig().register(resource).property(
                                        ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, "true")))
                .build();
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Test
    public void doTest() {

        Mockito.when(service.getMessage(Mockito.anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>(){
            @Override
            public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
                return "Hello " + (String)invocation.getArguments()[0];
            }
        });

        Response response = target("mock").queryParam("name", "peeskillet").request().get();
        Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        String message = response.readEntity(String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello peeskillet", message);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```